# How to get latitude and longitude in uwp app without internet?

Tags: javascript, winjs

Hi i am using HP Tablet with GNSS sensor built-in with it , so i want to get Geo-location that is latitude and longitude without internet but i am not able to get Geo-location coordinates without internet in my UWP desktop app in win-10, below is my code snippet, Any Help would be Appreciated.

```
function getGeoposition() {
    var desiredAccuracyInMeters = 0;

    Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.requestAccessAsync().done(
        function (accessStatus) {
            switch (accessStatus) {
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.allowed:

                    // If DesiredAccuracy or DesiredAccuracyInMeters are not set (or value is 0), DesiredAccuracy default is used.
                    var geolocator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
                    geolocator.desiredAccuracyInMeters = desiredAccuracyInMeters;

                    getGeopositionPromise = geolocator.getGeopositionAsync();
                    getGeopositionPromise.done(
                        function (pos) {

                            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Location updated", "sample", "status");

                        },
                        function (err) {

                            // i am getting error here saying "This operation returned because the timeout period expired."
                            WinJS.log && WinJS.log(err.message, "sample", "error");


                        }
                    );

                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Waiting for update...", "sample", "status");

                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.denied:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Access to location is denied.", "sample", "error");
                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.unspecified:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Unspecified error!", "sample", "error");
                    break;
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log(err, "sample", "error");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GPS data acquisition is relevant to environment of the device or the Sensor, if there are much shelters, it is hard to get the location data, such as the high buildings. Please try to test the code on an open place to get the GPS data. Besides, you can use other device with GPS support to make sure you can get the GPS data.

On other way, as the document [Guidelines for location-aware apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-and-checklist-for-detecting-location#recommendations):

> To help conserve power, set the desiredAccuracy property to indicate to the location platform whether your app needs high-accuracy data. If no apps require high-accuracy data, the system can save power by not turning on GPS providers.
>
> Set desiredAccuracy to HIGH to enable the GPS to acquire data.
>
> Set desiredAccuracy to Default and use only a single-shot call pattern to minimize power consumption if your app uses location info solely for ad targeting.

You can try to set the desiredAccuracy to HIGH to enable the GPS to acquire data.

More detail, see the document [Get the user's location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location) and the official [Geolocation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation) sample.